# Splitting field over the field of fractions $\mathbb{Z}_p(x)$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_p(t)$ for some $p$ prime number. Let $E$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^p-t$ over $F$.

(a) We need to show that degree of $E$ over $F$ is $p$, i.e. $[E:F]=p$.
(b) Also we need to show that $|G|=1$ where $G=Gal_F(E)$.

My work

Since $f'(x)=px^{p-1}=0$ then $f$ is inseparable, so $[E:F] \leq p$ and so if $[E:F]=d<p$ then there should be a minimal irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ but then this polynomial should divides $f$ which cannot happen as $f$ is inseparable, so $[E:F]$ must be $p$. Is that correct and sufficient argument for (a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)$ If $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)=0$ in $E$ then, $f(x)=x^p-\alpha^p=(x-\alpha)^p$ in $E[x]$ as the characteristic of the field is $p.$
Therefore this shows that, $f$ has only root $\alpha.$ Also, $f$ is irreducible over $F$ as $t\notin F^p.$ So, $E=F[x]/(f(x))$ and hence $[E:F]=p$

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, but can we conclude that the order of the Galois group is one because we only have one root so there is only one automorphism that fixes all the roots (which is one)? Thank you again!